# How to decode the markings on an SMD choke?

Tags: inductor, surface-mount, repair

I have a broken Ravensburger Tiptoi pen for kids. I opened it and the choke L7 broke. It is SMD and marked 420. I found out that [this could be either 42 micro or nano Henries](http://how-to.wikia.com/wiki/How_to_identify_inductor_markings). Question is, which is it, so I can order a replacement?

[image: tiptoi L7 marked 420 broke in half]

Comment: Due to construction and physical size it is very unlikely that it is nH.

Comment: Inductors vary in size depending on inductance AND current capability. What wire diameter is used in the broken part? It will narrow the search.

Comment: I have no clue. But the wire is very, very thin.

Comment: The other question to consider in this repair: why would such a simple part as few coils of wire around some piece of ferrite  break? There must be some reason. You need to find the reason.

Comment: The reason is: Toddlers throwing the pen around...

Comment: I think it is similar to this one: https://www.mouser.de/ProductDetail/Bourns/SDE0403A-470K

Comment: In our pen the same part is broken. Were you able to buy such a part and successfully fix your pen?

Comment: A colleague of mine with a very stead hand and a fine tipped soldering iron managed to solder the inductor wire back onto its pad. We then covered that part with a big drop of two component epoxy glue. The pen has been working fine ever since...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well considering the size, it's probably a 42uH inductor. 42nH is like on the same order the self inductance of a bit of random wire. As in, why would you use that kind of inductor if you can achieve the same inductance with a much smaller, cheaper component? Not to mention you won't even need a component with 42nH in that kind of application.

One way to check is to go on an electronics parts retailer like Digikey and search for 42uH and 42nH inductors and see which one seems more likely. From what I can see, there are a lot more turns than the 42nH inductor I found on digikey, so it's probably 42uH.

Since you're replacing the thing anyways, it might be wise to desolder the inductor and measure it with an LCR meter if you have one, or a simple function generator + resistor combo to get the transfer function. Even an arduino with a LPF will do.

Comment: When I check mouser for 42uH SMD, I don't get any hits. I find 41uH SMD, but they are huge, much larger than the one I have... Which inductors are smaller: uH or nH? I would have imagined nH, since nano is 10^3 less than uH, but maybe inductors do not work that way...?

Comment: Hmm, nH is smaller. Maybe the other guy is correct. Inductance scales with physical size (with all other variables held constant)